# XAML to codebehind

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, code-behind, datatrigger

I'm having troubles with converting XAML to codebehind.

I have this:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
   <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
      <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding state}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="GreenYellow"/>                                                  
         </DataTrigger>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding state}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
         </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

the `DataGrid` is populated via the (pseudo) `... new Dataview(ds.Tables[mytable]);`

now I'm trying to create the style and trigger in the code behind
but I'm having trouble with the Binding.

I have

```
BrushConverter brushConverter = new BrushConverter();
            Style setcolor = new Style();
            setcolor.TargetType = typeof(DataGridRow);
            DataTrigger setgreen = new DataTrigger();
            setgreen.Binding = new Binding("state");
            setgreen.Value = true;
            setgreen.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGrid.RowBackgroundProperty, brushConverter.ConvertFromString(Colors.GreenYellow.ToString())));
            setcolor.Triggers.Add(setgreen);
```

-Alas it is not working

Comment: You haven't set `setgreen.Binding`. And why the brush converter? You could just write `Brushes.GreenYellow`.

Comment: Didn't know about the brushes - ill do that instead. thanks. - and seems i left that part out, edited the question.

Comment: And I guess you want to set `DataGridRow.BackgroundProperty` instead of `DataGrid.RowBackgroundProperty`.

Comment: Worked! - its a miracle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the Setter's `Property` value from

```
DataGrid.RowBackgroundProperty
```

to

```
DataGridRow.BackgroundProperty
```

or the equivalent

```
Control.BackgroundProperty.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend building the `Style` itself in XAML, and then fetch it in your code-behind whenever you need it. For example, if everything happens in a `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class=...
             ...
>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyRowStyle" TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding state}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="GreenYellow"/>                                                  
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding state}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <!-- Your content here.. -->
```

..and in your code-behind:

```
var newGrid = new Dataview(ds.Tables[mytable]);
newGrid.RowStyle = this.Resources["MyRowStyle"] as Style;
```